# Adding an external stylesheet to a plugin

Tags: plugin-development

I apologize in advance if this question has been asked before.

I've created a plugin, and I'm trying to add an external stylesheet, but it's not working. Am I suppose to compress the plugin file and the stylesheet, and upload them then add a link to the stylesheet in the theme's php file?

Comment: please describe what u have tried in code till now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your plugin is working, you just don't get the stylesheet stuff to work?

In that case, you can use the wp_enqueue_scripts action.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style#Using_a_Hook

For usage with a stylesheet in the pluginfolder, you can use it like this:

```
function my_plugin_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-plugin-custom-styles', plugins_url('custom-styles.css' , __FILE__ ) );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_plugin_name_scripts' );
```

Happy Coding, 
Kuchenundkakao

Comment: Thank you for your response! Yes my plugin is working, i tried following your instructions and I continue to receive a "Fatal error" whenever i try to incorporate the stylesheet

Comment: What exactly is the Fatal Error saying?

Comment: Since it is a plugin so he should be hooking into more [appropriate action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts).